# Image Rotation : Perspective Transformation or Affline Transformation?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to rotate following image by 20 degree at center.
[image]

I can achieve this in OpenCV by two different ways:
 1. **Perspective Transformation**
 2. **Affine Transformation**

```
public void perspectiveXformation(String imgPath, List<Point> sourceCorners,
        List<Point> targetCorners) {
        // Load image in gray-scale format
        Mat matIncomingImg = Highgui.imread(imgPath, 0);
        // Check if size of list, process only if there are four points in list.
        if (sourceCorners.size() == 4) {
            // Convert vector points into Mat type of object.
            Mat sourceCornersMat =
                Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(sourceCorners);
            Mat targetCornersMat =
                Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(targetCorners);
            Mat matResultant = new Mat();
            // Do the Perspective transformation
            Mat matPtransform =
                Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(sourceCornersMat,
                    targetCornersMat);
            Imgproc.warpPerspective(matIncomingImg, matResultant,
                matPtransform,
                new Size(targetCorners.get(2).x, targetCorners.get(2).y));
            Highgui.imwrite("/tmp/perspectiveXform.png", matResultant);
        }
    }

public void afflineXformation(String imgPath, Point center) {
    Mat selectedMat = Highgui.imread(imgPath, 0);
    Mat res = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 20, 1.0);
    Mat newMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.warpAffine(selectedMat, newMat, res, selectedMat.size());
    Highgui.imwrite("/tmp/afflineXform.png", newMat);
}
```

Which is the preferred way of rotating image ?

Comment: That depends: Do you turn your head, or rotate the paper?

Comment: For a pure rotation, Affine seems like it's a better match; rotating via perspective transform seems like a side effect. And the code is simpler too.

Comment: @beaker I want to rotate the paper

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree that code is simpler for Affine but what surprises me is that quality of output image in case of Perspective transform is better than Affine(I mean to say, output image by Affine seems to be blurry). Is this expected or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: "...output image by Affine seems to be blurry" Ah, so we finally get to the real question. :) Is the output image quality any better using perspective transforms? I would expect not, if you are performing equivalent transformations. All in all, I agree with @MarkRansom; affine transforms seem more natural for what you're trying to achieve.